# Is there a general rule for the usage of hyphens in compound words?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-words

For example for words like in-depth or long-term I would always use a hyphen, and I tend to favor using them in general unless I'm certain there *shouldn't* be one, but often I find both used for words like this. Can both be correct in different situations? Is there a general rule for when you should or should not use hyphens in compound words?

Comment: Might be worth doing a search here on hyphens in compound words. It's a fairly common subject for questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general rule for the use of hyphens in compound words.

Compound words can be formed by combination of different kinds of words, i.e., noun/noun, adjective/noun, verb/preposition, preposition/noun etc. In any of the cases, there is no rule for hyphenation. One must know if a hyphen is involved in a word or not. For example, the word 'laughing-gas' is often written as 'laughing gas'. Although using hyphens avoids ambiguity it is often not used without posing any trouble. For instance, consider a sentence, 'nitrous oxide is commonly known as laughing gas'. In this sentence, most people would interpret the word 'laughing gas' as one and not as a gas that is laughing. However, it is good if a hyphen is used between the two components of the compound word making it 'laughing-gas'. This would always prove to be helpful.

Some other words like hot dog, takeout, potbelly etc. are widely used without hyphens. Earlier, takeout was usually written as 'take-out' but the hyphen got out of fashion over time but it is absolutely correct to use a hyphen in the word 'take-out'. Both the forms are correct.

Americans tend to avoid the use of hyphens while British like to use hyphens. For example, the oxford dictionary uses 'pot-belly' while the American heritage dictionary uses 'potbelly'.

**When two words are joined together as one word without any space in between them, it is called closed form. For example,  keyboard, toothbrush, underworld etc.**

**When two words are brought together to form one word with space between them, then it is called as open form. For example, hot dog, life boat etc.**

**When two or more words are connected with one or more hyphens in between them then they are said to be in hyphenated form. For example, brother-in-law, runner-up, kilowatt-hour etc.**

Comment: This is a well written, thoughtful answer. The only addition I'd like to see are some citations (links to the dictionary definitions you use as examples and maybe a style guide for your rules). We also have some canonical questions on this site, which means that it's possible this question will be closed as a duplicate. Also, welcome!

Comment: Here's an excellent article about the details: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/spelling-using-compound-words-guide

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/594134/43466