# Do compound words have any logic?

Tags: open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated, compound-words

My mother tongue is Finnish and Finns are famous for using really long compound words. English also has compound words, too, and there's [a great example list of compound words on another site](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-compounds.html).

Some examples from that list:

1. Closed-form compound words: snowball, mailbox, grandmother, basketball, skateboard, schoolhouse
2. Hyphenated compound words: long-term, mother-in-law, check-in
3. Open compound words: peanut butter, ice cream, real estate

Can I create my own compound words to be used in formal context? If so, is there any logic to figure out if my newly created compound word is closed-form, hyphenated or open compound word? And even the above list is not complete because you have to write "ice-cream cone", if I've understood correctly.

(For example, in case of Finnish, the rules are very simple: all compound words are closed but if previous word ends with the same vowel as the second part starts with, you have to add hyphen between those parts in written form. This is required because otherwise both vowels would be accidentally read as part of one syllable. In spoken form there's no difference because syllable break between the parts is enough in all cases.)

Comment: The age of the compound word alone doesn't seem to be the correct explanation to convert it to closed-form because "skateboard" is way too young word to be in the same class as telephone or automobile.

Comment: I'd leave out *ice-cream* as an example of hyphenated terms, since the hyphenating belongs to the special role taken. Then, I'd presume the open form until I can see a reason for some closing: is healthcare distinct from health care?

Comment: I don't agree with much of what you say. For example "ice cream" is a straightforward compound noun.

Comment: Note that a compound word is written as a single word. Whether the two bases are hyphenated or not is irrelevant. The so-called open compounds are almost always not compounds at all but sequences of words, phrases consisting of head+modifier.

Comment: Hyphenated words tend to evolve into closed form over time. Examples include e-mail (email), start-up (startup), clean-up (cleanup), bumble-bee (bumblebee) etc. Some hyphenated words also evolved in the opposite direction into two words for example ice-cream is now ice cream, test-tube is now test tube etc. The only consistent rule is that the "correct" spelling is how the majority of media spell the word.

Comment: @slebetman "Ice-cream" is still a compound word, hyphenated of course.

Comment: I think open compounds are still considered compounds because you cannot have any other words between those words that make a compound. For example, you have to put any adjectives before "ice cream" instead of using adjective in the middle. It's technically written with a space (due historical reasons?) but it might as well always have hyphen because you cannot split it.

Comment: The word "email" is an interesting case. If I've understood correctly it started as compound word "electronic mail", then got abbreviated to "e-mail" and is now just email. However, one could argue that it *should* be written "e-mail" to better match e-book and e-commerce where the hyphen doesn't seem to be optional. In addition, it's technically a combination of an abbreviated and non-abbreviated words which should use hyphen as a general rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is interesting you should ask about ***logic*** when it comes to language. Sometimes *logic* may seem incompatible with language, but then it cannot be, since language is *not chaotic*. *[LinguisticPulse](https://linguisticpulse.com/2013/05/02/on-the-logics-of-language-yes-logics-with-an-s/#:%7E:text=Language%20is%20not%20governed%20by,I%20sat%20on%20chair%20the%E2%80%9D.)* says:

> Language is *not governed by Logic in the formal sense*, ***but even though it’s arbitrary we know it’s also not completely random***.  An individual language, like English, has particular ***consistencies*** about it.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/spelling-using-compound-words-guide) has a long article about compound words and I think there you will find an answer. I find this catchy sentence particularly helpful:

> There aren't fast rules to forming compounds, but there are ***patterns***.

These *patterns* may be included in what *LinguisticPulse* called ***consistencies***.

The article speaks about the three ways of spelling compound words you mention:

> Compounds are written in one of three ways: ***solid*** (*teapot*), ***hyphenated*** (*player-manager*), or ***open*** (which ranges from phrases such as *off and on* or *little by little* to combinations like *washing machine*—have a *field day* finding more). Because of the variety in formation, the choice among the styles for a given compound represents **one of the most vexing of all style issues** writers—and lexicographers—encounter.

So there is controversy about the matter, but let it not scare us.

> For some terms, it is often acceptable to choose freely among open, hyphenated, and solid alternatives, even though the term has been used in English for an extended period (for instance, *lifestyle*, *life-style*, or *life style*). *Although the styling that ultimately takes hold for a compound may be **determined by nothing more than editorial and writerly preference**, there are patterns of new compounds as they become established in the English language*. **Compound nouns**, for instance, are ***usually** written as one word*; **compound verbs** are ***generally** written as two*; **compound adjectives** are ***often** written with a hyphen*. But note that we added "usually," "generally," and "often"—we're hedging.

The article goes on to tackle compounds in detail. It gives a pretty accurate idea about the dynamics of compounds formation in English.

Comment: However, a dash is never right in the context of a hyphenated form! MW have "life–style" instead of "life-style". Actually that's an interesting one because there may be a very subtle difference between *lifestyle* and *life style*.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't realised about the dash. It might be a formatting style though. It has some longer dashes as actual dashes.

Comment: Punctuation is very unstable. Compounds change all the time and writing does not keep up with them any better than it has with English vowels. The logic is not for punctuation -- that's just recent fads; the logic is for the meaning. There are about a dozen common forms.

Answer (score 2):

Compound words are constructed according to a  fundamental logic.

> (**CoGeL**) [D] COMPOUNDING:
> adding one base to another, such that usually the one placed in front in some sense subcategorizes the one that follows; eg:
> blackbird, armchair, bott1e-feed […]

- long-term: the category is  that of the terms; the subcategories are characterized by words  such as  "short", "mid"  and others; therefore  those  terms  come first: "*short-term*", "*mid-term*".

If you  think  carefully  you see  that a similar thinking process  applies to all the following.

- snowball, mailbox, grandmother, basketball, skateboard, schoolhouse, peanut butter, ice cream

Two terms in the list,  "mother-in-law"  and "check-in",  are not compounds. "Mother-in-law" is  obtained  through *suffixation* (suffix "*-in-law*") and "check-in" is obtained  through so-called *reconversion* (of  the verb   "to check  in")

> Can I create my own compound words to be used in formal context? If so, is there any logic to figure out if my newly created compound word is closed-form, hyphenated or open compound word? And even the above list is not complete because you have to write "ice-cream cone", if I've understood correctly.

1/ Yes  you  can;   however  you have to do  that in  cases   of   sufficient necessity,  when you discover    a new concept,  which, therefore has not     yet  been named. Do  not  forget,  compounds have   to    be defined  otherwise people do not    know  what  they     mean.  So  you can  do    that    in   a  thesis ,  for  instance, where the   definition will  be deduced from  an explanation,  or you  can write a definition (not  so usual).
2/   Of course,   compounds can be  used for  compouding.
3/ There is  no rule   about     hyphenation.

[image]

Comment: What is the point of the Ngram you've supplied?

Comment: @BillJ To show that a  large majority of people do not use a  hyphen; it must be clear from that that there is no  rule.

Comment: Google returns 32% more hits for "ice-cream" than for "ice cream". "Ice-cream" is of course a compound noun, and careful writers will write it as a single word "ice-cream".

Comment: @BillJ It remains that when they write the compound  they  use  less  often a hyphen;  overall they do not think  it  matters  much.  BTW,  I found  "ice cream"  (ice 'cream   _also_ ' ice cream, esp  in the US and Canada) in the OALD, although in the SOED it is "ice-cream" and "ice-cream  parlour".

Comment: No: I've just told you that there are 32% more hits on Google for "ice-cream" than for "ice cream".

Comment: @BillJ No to what?

Comment: You said "It remains that when they write the compound they use less often a hyphen", Google shows otherwise, with 32% more hits for hyphenated "ice-cream" than for unhyphenated "ice cream", i.e. the opposite of what you said.

Comment: @BillJ I meant the compound "ice-cream cone". (Sorry, it didn't occur  to me that this  could be confusing.)